# How to make one button for open and close div, in this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#content1').hide();

            $('a#open').click(function(){

            $('#content1').show('slow');

   });

   $('a#close').click(function(){
        $('#content1').hide('slow');
        })

      });
```

in this code of toogle open and close button is different

`<a>` and `<a id="close">`

I want to make same button `<a>` for open and close and want to give different background image for open and close position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#content1').slideToggle();
});
```

If you would like to change their css ,you can re-write it in the following way.

```
$('a').click(function(){

       if ($('#content1').is(":visible"))
       {
            //change your css here
            //for eg. $(#content1).css('background-image', first_image);
            $('#content1').hide('slow');
       }
       else{ 
            //change your css here
            //for eg. $(#content1).css('background-image', second_image);
            $('#content1').show('slow');
       }

});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this working. now how to add different css class for open and close position to `<a>`

Comment: I found another way and i'm using this `$(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); return false;`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`Toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) section of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own function called ShowOrHide() and call that when the button is clicked.

In ShowOrHide, see if the div is already visible/hidden and do the opposite.

Then you'll only need one button to perform both operations.

Comment: How pls help . I'm noob in jquery. Thanks

Comment: See the link to toggle above, it's much better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ps4F/) I made a while ago. (With a lot of help from SO)

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Hope it helps.